# For loop - big-O

Tags: big-o

I am trying to do this problem out of a book and am struggling to understand the answer.

```
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
   if ((i % 2) == 0) {
      outVal[i] = inVals[i] * i
   }
}
```

here's how I was breaking it down:
I=0 -> executes 1 time

I < n and ++I each execute once every iteration. so 1n+1n = 2n.

the if statement contains 2 operands, so now we are at 4n+1.

the contents of the if statement only executes n/2 times, so we are at 4n+1+n/2

however, big O drops those terms off, leaving us with N as the answer

Here's what I don't get: the explanation for the answer of my problem says this: 
outVal[i] = inVals[i] * i; executes every other loop iteration, so the total number of operations include: 1 operation at the start of the loop, 3 operations every loop iteration, 1 operation every other loop iteration, and 1 operation for the final loop condition check.

how are there only 3 operations in the loop? I counted 4 as stated above. Please let me know the rationale behind this.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is measured by the time/space you take to accomplish a task. `i<N` and `++i` do not take time dependant of your space variable N (the length of the loop).

You must not add how many times an operation is done and sum all of them - you must, instead, choose the one who takes more time or space, as that's the algorithm bottleneck. In a loop, msot of the operations run equal times, so we use the length of the loop as its complexity space or time.

The loop will run N times, so that's its complexity -> O(n)

Inside the loop, the if scope will run N/2 times, as you correctly said -> O(n/2)

But those runs are already added to the first loop iterations. You will not add it since there are no external iterations.

So, the complexity of the algorithm is O(n).

Regarding the operations, the 3 are:

- Checking I

  Adding 1 to I

  The if condition

All of them are done in every iteration.